# Javascript, comparing two arrays in order while skipping non-matching indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
var arr2 = [7,1,8,2,12,3,4,28,5]
```

I need to go through arr2 looking for matches to arr1, but it has to be in order (1,2,3,4,5). As you can see in arr2, the order does exists, but there are some numbers in between.

[7,***1***,8,***2***,12,***3***,***4***,28,***5***]

I have about 50 arrays similar to arr2, so I need to look through each one, and when I find a match, push it out to a "results" object. Small issue though is that some arrays will not have the entire match, may only have 1,2,3 or any variation of the search. Also, if the array I'm searching in is NOT in order, (IE: starts at 2,3,4) skip over it entirely.

The idea is to loop through these arrays, and when I find a match, add a count to the results array.

For example, using arr1 as the search, go through these arrays:

[7,***1***,8,***2***,12,***3***,***4***,28,***5***],
[7,***1***,8,***2***,12,***3***,***4***],
[7,8,***1***,***2***],
[***1***,***2***,***3***]

and have a result that looks like this (a dictionary of what was searched for, and a count of what was found) :

```
{1:4, 2:4, 3:3, 4:2, 5:1}
```

I tried doing a bunch of for-loops, but I can't figure out how to skip over a number that I'm not looking for, and continue onto the next iteration, while saving the results into a dictionary object.

Comment: One sec, I'll add some code from what I tried

Comment: whats path? an array?

Comment: It's a string. Can be anything really, it's user supplied

Comment: whats does it have to do with your question?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question. The question is about searching through an array in the order of another array. Why do you ask about it?

Comment: because its confusing, and has nothing to do with the question, so why post it? you need to show what you have tried...not just setup a loop.

Comment: I don't know where to start, which is why I've come asking. Looping through an array is easy, doing it in the order of another array is what I can't figure out. I can show you a basic for-loop if you need one.

Comment: Just use `arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])`, map it to fhe values, and check later, if the values was in order.

Comment: David, please take a look at my answer, it's exactly what you are looking for. It's been downvoted because I initially misunderstood your post but I updated it with a fix just now.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this:

```js
var needle = [1,2,3,4,5]
var collection = [[7,1,8,2,12,3,4,28,5], [7,1,8,2,12,3,4], [7,8,1,2], [1,2,3]]

// start with an object
var results = {}
// populate object with zeros
needle.forEach(function (i) { results[i] = 0 })
// define an index to iterate through collection
var i = 0
// define an index to conditionally iterate through "arr1"
var j = 0
// define an index to iterate through collection arrays 
var k = 0
// define surrogate for the arrays in the collection
var arr

while (i < collection.length) {
  
  // get collection array
  arr = collection[i]
  // reset the indices
  j = 0
  k = 0

  while (k < arr.length) {
    // if same element on needle is in a collection array 
    if (needle[j] === arr[k]) {
      // save it in an object starting at 1
      results[needle[j]]++
      j++ // increment needle
    }
    k++ // increment array in collection
  }
  i++ // increment collection
}

console.log(results) // {1:4, 2:4, 3:3, 4:2, 5:1}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: @Bálint By who? What standard are you following? [I'm not the only thinking along these lines](https://github.com/feross/standard#rules), you know.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Does this not post not answer the question?

Comment: I don't know how I managed to ignore half the post... Regardless, I've already updated my answer, pretty sure it's producing the right output now, and there is one other answer here with no downvotes — it produces the wrong output! Let's reconsider this guys, please.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks man! Also, I agree with you about the semi-colons. No need to use them with Javascript. All they do (in my opinion) is add extra size to a file

Comment: Awesome, glad I was able to help :)
Good luck, David!

Comment: And it's fast too! Wish I could give you extra points. The collection currently has 974 arrays in it. Completes in about 4ms.

Comment: @JordanHendrix He did, but then he took it back and gave it to "le_m" because of the "reduce" method... =/

Comment: I removed that answer from being correct as well. arrow functions are not available in Safari right now, so this makes my app broken. If you can change yours to NOT use arrow functions, I'll remark as answered.

Comment: @David There you go.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let list = [[7,1,8,2,12,3,4,28,5], [7,1,8,2,12,3,4], [7,8,1,2], [1,2,3]];
let search = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Initialize result with zeros:
let result = search.reduce((result, next) => {
  result[next] = 0;
  return result;
}, {});

// Increment result for items found:
list.forEach(array => {
  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length && j < search.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == search[j]) {
      ++result[search[j]];
      ++j;
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this one because it uses the "reduce" method, making it shorter

Comment: I'm changing this from the correct answer. arrow functions are not available in Safari right now, so this makes my app broken. If you can change it to NOT use arrow functions, I'll remark as answered.

Comment: @David Since your question is a general JS question, I will keep my answer as it is (I think it is more useful to other readers with the same question). If you need compatibility with older JS engines, you can (in most cases) replace arrow functions `a => {...}` with `function (a) {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var orign = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr = [[7,1,8,2,12,3,4,28,5], [7,1,8,2,12,3,4], [7,8,1,2], [1,2,3]];

//temp result
var arrTmp = [];

for (var x in arr){
  var match = 0;
  var mis = 1;
  var curIndex = 0;
  var cur = orign[curIndex];
  var arrTmpX = [];
  for(var y in arr[x]){
    if(arr[x][y] !== cur){
      mis=1;
    }else{
      //add match after mismatch
        arrTmpX.push(cur);
      curIndex++
      cur = orign[curIndex];
    }
  }
  arrTmp.push(arrTmpX);
}

//calc result
var result = {};
for (var x in orign){
  result[orign[x]] = 0;
  for(var y in arrTmp){
    if(arrTmp[y].length>x)result[orign[x]]++;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

this works

Comment: It's a good start, but the result is not accurate. the number 2 is shows up in order (after the number 1) 4 times, but the result only counts it 3 times. The number 3 shows up 3 times, counted once.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];

var arr2 = [7,1,8,2,12,3,4,28,5];


function givenTwoArrays(a,b, obj){
    var obj = obj || {};
    var cond = true;

    function otherMatch(indexFound,elementFound){
        var indexOnA = a.indexOf(elementFound);
        return a.some(function(ele, idx){
            if(idx > indexOnA)
                 return b.some(function(bele,bidx){
                    return ele == bele && bidx < indexFound;
                });
        });


    }


    a.map(function(aele,idx){
        if(cond){
            var indexFound = b.findIndex(function(bele){
                return aele == bele;
            });
            if(typeof indexFound !== 'undefined'){
                if(!otherMatch(indexFound,aele)){
                    if(typeof obj[aele] !== 'undefined')
                        obj[aele]++;
                    else{
                        obj[aele] = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    cond = false;
                }
            }else
                cond = false;
        }

    });

    return obj;
}
console.log("first pass");
console.log(givenTwoArrays(arr1,arr2))
console.log("second pass");
console.log(givenTwoArrays(arr1,arr2,{
  "1": 1,
  "2": 1,
  "3": 1,
  "4": 1,
  "5": 1
}));
```

I think this will work, just need to add a little recursion!